# Where did the Text Selection API go?

Tags: javascript, html, interface, selection

Two years ago the HTML5 standard dropped the chapter "Text Selection API" which contained a specification of the `Selection` interface:

```
[Stringifies] interface Selection {
  readonly attribute Node anchorNode;
  readonly attribute long anchorOffset;
  readonly attribute Node focusNode;
  readonly attribute long focusOffset;
  readonly attribute boolean isCollapsed;
  void collapse(in Node parentNode, in long offset);
  void collapseToStart();
  void collapseToEnd();
  void selectAllChildren(in Node parentNode);
  void deleteFromDocument();
  readonly attribute long rangeCount;
  Range getRangeAt(in long index);
  void addRange(in Range range);
  void removeRange(in Range range);
  void removeAllRanges();
};
```

See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/editing.html#selection

I remember encountering this interface in another standard, but I forgot which one. Could anyone please refresh my memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It moved to WHATWG's [DOM Range spec](http://html5.org/specs/dom-range.html). The Range portion of that document has very recently (within the last week or so) been migrated to W3C's [DOM4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-dom-20110915/#ranges).

This leaves the WHATWG Range spec in the position of being rather misleadlingly named. I'm not sure whether there are plans to move the Selection stuff again but I wouldn't bet against it.

### Update February 2013

The Selection portion of the spec is currently found in the [HTML Editing APIs spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#selections).

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. Btw how can one view the list of specs inside the http://html5.org/specs/ folder? Do I really have to do a [Google search](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fhtml5.org%2Fspecs%2F&pbx=1&oq=site:http%3A%2F%2Fhtml5.org%2Fspecs%2F&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1073l2693l0l3657l6l4l0l0l0l0l209l636l0.3.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=b659e1e8b520709&biw=1492&bih=1071)?

Comment: Btw would you possibly know what the state of browser implementation for the `Selection` interface is? (which browsers implement it)

Comment: @Šime: I can't remember whether I've seen one somewhere, but I can't find one now. The best I've found is http://platform.html5.org/

Comment: @Šime: Current versions of all major browsers implement the majority of the `Selection` interface, although there is some variation (`modify()` is a relatively recent addition and is not well supported, `extend()` likewise and is not supported in IE 9, `toString()` is inconsistently implemented and does not match the spec in many cases, plus probably many other issues). The spec itself has some outstanding issues.