# Replacing selected with another text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace selected text with another text.
Consider following is the line of text.

> Hello world.Good morning. Hello world. Good morning.

Here if I select second `morning` text and I want replace morning text with night. So that output need to look like this:

> Hello world.Good morning. Hello world. Good night.

I tried replace function, but it is replacing first morning text.
Can anyone suggest solution for this?

Comment: Where is this text located? In a `textarea`/`input` or part of the text of a DOM element?

Comment: Are you having problems with the selected text or with the replacing?
You can replace all occurrences using `str.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');` (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064956/replace-all-occurrences-in-a-string )

Comment: similar problem
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183/replacing-the-nth-instance-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

To get the current selection in HTML5, use the [DOM Range API](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ranges).

To edit the selection, the [Selections API](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#selections) can be used.

See also: [Where did the Text Selection API go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471515/where-did-the-text-selection-api-go)

If you use jQuery, then use the [wrapSelection plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/wrapSelection)

Comment: Can you show me a sample example, that helps me to get clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v2MV4/1/)

```
function swapSelection(swapText) {
  var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange();
  if (sel != "") {
    if (sel.getRangeAt) {
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      var newNode = document.createElement("span");
      newNode.setAttribute('class', 'swapclass');
      range.surroundContents(newNode);
    } else {
      sel.pasteHTML('<span class="swapclass">' + sel.htmlText + '</span>');

    }
    $('.swapclass').replaceWith(swapText);
  }
}

$('button').click(function () {
  swapSelection('night');
});
```